# Add custom metadata to items in A360 using Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am looking for a way to tag an item in A360 with metadata using Autodesk Forge. For example: I have a revit file stored in A360 and I want to put metadata on this object such as author, department, duedate etc. 
Is this even supported in the API?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as far as I can see in the [Data Management API Reference](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/), there is no such feature exposed yet. I'm checking with the development team and will log a wish about it.

Suggested workarounds would be:

1/ Store the data in the revit file itself to some properties which get extracted, so you are able to access them from the [Model Derivative API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2)

2/ Use a custom side database where you store the item URN mapped to third party metadata

3/ Add a file to DM which contains metadata attributes

Comment: Ok! Is it possible to extract parameter values from a Revit model using the Model Derivative API?

Comment: I'm not a revit expert but I don't think it is possible yet unfortunately. Basically the data you have access with derivative API is the same properties you can see when you load a model in the viewer and open the property panel.

Comment: I got the feedback that uploading data with custom attributes will soon be possible. Another suggestion for the moment is to use an attachment for example a json file that would contain your attributes, which is currently supported by the API: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/create-attachment

Comment: How can you get the metadata from a model or the equivalent of this file? https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-navigation.sample/blob/master/www/rac.json

Comment: This is a specific sample, I'm not very familiar with it. The Forge Model Derivatives API gives you access to whatever metadata is exported with the original model, please take a look at the documentation: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2. The endpoint you are interested about would be GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties. Hope that helps.